# never remove active class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I added a class on my specific button, the button is on the slider, when I clicking the arrow of slider, the slider automatically adding active class to another button, I want to write some method which will never remove a class of my specific button how can I do it?

**this is the code which is adding active class**

```
($(item).parent('.owl-stage').parent('.owl-stage-outer').parent('.img-block').children('.owl-dots').children('button').not('.displayed-slider-btn')[2]).addClass('active');
```

Comment: Just use another class. Class "active"  is used by Owl plugin, you can not disable it without crashing the source code.
For ex. add specific class "enabled" and copy for it all css style from class "active"

Comment: Please check good practices of asking a question. No one is able to help you if don't provide a good example of the problem you are experiencing. Now you will have just guessing of what may help.

Comment: @Reflective ok i get it thank you

Comment: @AleksandrAbramov thank you so much write your answer on the answers space i will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use another class. Class "active" is used by Owl plugin, you can not disable it without crashing the source code. For ex. add specific class "enabled" and copy for it all css style from class "active"